# Spring Stream trying to create Topic instead of Queue in IBM MQueue

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to figure out how to use Spring Boot Streams with MQueue using [spring-cloud-stream-binder-ibm-mq](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-ibm-mq). I can connect to MQueue but get a `Could not provision topic 'queue///EMB_DEV_QUEUE'` and `MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'`. I did confirm with the administrator that it is a queue and not a topic.

I can connect using some sample code using `MQQueueConnectionFactory` based on [simplest-sample-applications-using-websphere-mq-jms](https://hursleyonwmq.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/simplest-sample-applications-using-websphere-mq-jms/) so I know MQueue is working.

Here is my program. I have used the same pattern for Kafka with success.

```
@EnableBinding({Sink.class, Source.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class MQueueStreamApplication {

    private final static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    private final        Logger        logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MQueueStreamApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "2000"))
    public MessageSource<String> timeSource() {
        return () -> {
            String message = String.format("Timed Message %d", counter.incrementAndGet());

            logger.info("Producing Message: {}", message);

            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).setHeader("Message-Type", "mqueue-stream").build();
        };
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)
    public void serviceSink(Message<String> message) {
        String payload = String.valueOf(message.getPayload());

        logger.info("Received Message: {} [{}]", payload, message.getHeaders());
    }

}
```

Here is my `application.yml`. I have tried with and without the `queue:///` prefix. The sample program works with the prefix.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: queue:///EMB_DEV_QUEUE
          group: mqueue-stream
#          binder: ibmmq
        output:
          destination: queue:///EMB_DEV_QUEUE

ibmmq:
  host: vm-dev-q01.corp.int
  port: 1414
  channel: EMB_DEV_CHANNEL
  queueManager: EMB_DEV_QMGR
```

Here is my Gradle build.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms-ibm-mq:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.RELEASE"
    }
}
```

I built the `spring-cloud-stream-binder-ibm-mq` following the instructions. I got the two required jars from the MQueue installation. The manifest said version `9.0.0.0` so I used `9` in the `pom.xml`

I am new to MQueue and have limited experience with Streams. I have been able to connect to Kafka successfully. I would appreciate any help.

Wes.

Comment: I tried to follow the same instruction to first build spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms-ibm-mq:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar using com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.2.0.jar and com.ibm.mq.pcf-9.1.2.0.jar. I was able to run package it without running tests because the tests were giving errors. Then I created a new spring-cloud-stream application and added spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms-ibm-mq:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar dependency similar to yours application but I am getting the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`. Any idea whats causing it and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Stream uses a more opinionated infrastructure than regular JMS/IBM-MQ applications in order to be able to implement features like consumer groups and partitioning - in this case the destination is a topic - see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-ibm-mq#how-it-works for details.

Comment: I read that a few times was still not too sure. Probably my lack of experience with MQ. The IBM docs imply that a Topic is just a label but stepping through the code it appears to be accessing Topics and then Queues with in a Topic using a topic.queue convention. That sounds like a structure or is that just a Subscription? My goal is to have a consumer that returns the message if it can't process it. First I thought Client_Ack but now thinking 2 destinations. One for retry and other if retry fails. Do they have to be Topics? Want retry to be same Queue with a delay. Fail to be different. Thx

Comment: @Wes, I tried to run the tests for `spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms-ibm-mq:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` but it fails, could you please explain how did you manage to successfully package `spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms-ibm-mq:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar` and use it inside spring-cloud-stream app. Thanks